# Meaning of (n & 1 << b) in C++

Tags: c++, c++14, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

While referring a C++ code written by someone else in CodeChef for a particular problem I found a new way(at least for me) of writing a conditional statement like this:  `if (n & 1 << b)`.
The entire code snippet(a function) is as follows:

```
int Solve(int tim, int n)
{
    if (tim < 0) 
         return 1;

    int res = 0;
    for (int b = Maxb - 1; b >= 0; b--)
        if (n & 1 << b) 
        {
            int my = b - __builtin_popcount(tim & ((1 << b) - 1));
            res += 1 << my;

            if (tim & 1 << b) 
                 return res;
        }

    res++;
    return res;
}
```

I know the bitwise AND operation and also a left shift operation means when we use separately. However, here the combination of both in a conditional statement made me confuse to read the logic. When I searched for the references, I couldn't find a situation where both operations come up together. Therefore, can anybody tell me the meaning or what exactly going on here?

Comment: Operator precedence means it’s `n & (1 << b)`. Does that help?

Comment: Shifting 1 left b places gives you the same result as raising 2 to the power of b.

Comment: if `b` is 0, it will be `false` since it won't depend on `n` at all. if `b > 0`, it will depend solely on `n`. it's a weird construct, but plausible for kernel hackers.

Comment: @Ryan: that means it does first left shift and then AND, right. That's what I would like to clarify.

Comment: It shifts 1 to the left b places and then &'s the result with n.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @Omer: Okay. Now it's clear. Thanks to all for the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a check to see if the bit at position 'b' in the binary representation of n is turned on or off.

```
if (n & 1 << b)
```

is essentially

```
if (n & (1 << b))
```

because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

these are the values that 1 << b gets (righthand side is in **binary**):

For b == 0, `(1 << b) == ...000000001`

For b == 1, `(1 << b) == ...000000010`

For b == 2, `(1 << b) == ...000000100`

For b == 3, `(1 << b) == ...000000100`

For b == 3, `(1 << b) == ...000001000`

For b == 4, `(1 << b) == ...000010000`

and so on.

When you `&` the value `1 << b` with `n` you essentially turn off all of `n`'s bits except for the bit in the location corresponding to the `1` in the binary representation of `1 << b`.

This means that you would only get a non-zero result for `n & (1 << b)` if the bit of `n` that was in the location corresponding to the `1` bit of `(1 << b)` was turned on. If it wasn't, all of the bits would turn off and since it was already `0`, it would stay `0` and the end result would be `0`.

The `if` statement receives this final result, if it's positive (the bit was on) it will enter the `if`, otherwise (if the bit was off), the end result would be 0 and the `if` statement would consider the statement `n & (1 << b)` to be `false`.

Comment: yeah... everything is clear now. Thanks a lot, Omer for a detail explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Per http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

`<<` takes precedence over `&`. So, like @Ryan's comment, `(n & 1 << b)` is equivalent to `(n & (1 << b))`